# Primefaces panel width auto fit browser

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm doing project in primefaces. In primefaces how content based panel has to fixed.

```
<p:panel>
........
</p:panel>
Css:
.ui-panel{width:-moz-fit-content}
```

It will work in mozila browser only. if any style will common support all browser or any other inbuild style in primefaces.
I need panel content based width fixed automatically and avoid unwanted space.